# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Tags: python

```
open(r'C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\Private')
```

When I run this code I get the error "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:" but I don't know how to fix it? This should open up the folder "Private" but it always pops that error, I'm on Windows 8.

Comment: Means you don't have permission to read that file.

Answer (score 3):

You should run your python with administrative privileges. On OSX or linux OS `sudo python <file>` in the terminal will suffice.